# How to declare the state of "Values in status line" switch in Pine Script V5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

We can switch it off in the Settings Panel of indicators. How can we do it in the script itself?

[image: Values in status line, indicator settings panel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change that option programmatically but you can have the same behavior with the `display` argument.

Many people don't know this but you can actually do some math operations on the `display` argument.

For instance, if you do `display=display.all - display.status_line`, it will display the result everywhere except the status line which is what you want.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
plot(close, "Test", display=display.all - display.status_line)
```